# Complement of AWS FsX in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-bucket

a few weeks ago, I've set up a microservice in *AWS* including Windows Virtual Machines (EC2) and a FsX Share (including Active Directory). I've decided to use a FsX instead of a s3 Bucket, as the customer wants to mount the share as drive in the Windows EC2s without using any other tools.

Now, I've to do the very same in Google Cloud Platform. I'm quite new to GCP and just recognized one possible way for creating a share - the Storage Bucket. Unfortantely there are restrictions for *Windows* Compute Engines: it is not possible to mount the Bucket in a Compute Engine out of the box - so I'm using gcsfuse-win for mounting it.
I wonder whether this is the best solution...
Do you've any experiences with regard to establish shares in GCP - what would you prefer if you have to use Windows Compute Engines? I'd prefer a solution close to the AWS FsX concept - if there exists a similar approach in GCP.

Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: I've just recognized https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/mounting-fileshares?hl=de#windows
But I'm still curious about your advices

Answer (score 0):

I'm very sorry for answering my own question. It seems that "Filestore" instance is the desired resource related to establishing a file share according to my requirements.

It's a proper solution, especially if you'd like to mount a share as drive in a Windows Compute Engine without installing further tools (for Windows) as it is necessary for the Storage Bucket.

[image]

[image]

The related documentation is useful:

https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/create-instance-console?hl=de